# Swapping occurrences of 2 symbols in a string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a String where I want to replace all Kommas by Dots and all Dots by Komma

my current Solution:

```
public String swapCommaDot(String toReplace){
String randomSequence = "AKP5W4TwcbxvkHUKwGTS"; 
//random.org generated Password
// longer sequence = lesser risk that this sequence is contained in toReplace
toReplace.replaceAll(",",randomSequence);
toReplace.replaceAll("\\.",",");
toReplace.replaceAll(randomSequence,"\\.");
}
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why don't you create a new empty string and just add all toReplace characters, but before adding test if it is a comma or a dot, and just change when one of these occurs?

Comment: this way, you'll never get a password that mess your algorithm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static  void swap(String s){
        int index=0;
        char[] chars=s.toCharArray();
        for(char c:chars){

            if('.'==c)
            chars[index]=',';
            else if(','==c){
                chars[index]='.';
            }
            index++;

        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(chars));
    }
```